# Making text change colors with jquery (non-stop flashing)

Tags: jquery

What's the easiest way to make text toggle between two colors/classes **continuously** with jquery?

Comment: Uh oh. Just don't end up on http://www.webpagesthatsuck.com/!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A simple example:

CSS

```
div { color: red; }
div.blinking { color: blue; }
```

jQuery (at `DOMready` event)

```
var el = $('div');
setInterval(function() {
   el.toggleClass('blinking');
}, 1000);
```

Example fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/gLEuP/

---

Otherwise, you could avoid at all JS on modern browser and use only CSS3 animation, e.g.

```
@keyframes blink {
    0% { color  : red; }
    49% { color : red; }
    50% { color : blue }
    100% { color: blue; }
}

div {
    animation: blink 2s linear infinite;
}
```

Example codepen (with vendor prefixes): http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NPJBbe

Note, avoid to set a too small delay, it could hurt people affected by [photosensitive epilepsy](http://juicystudio.com/article/photosensitive-epilepsy.php) (and annoying for everyone else)

Comment: Yep... and place that code into the `$(document).ready` function :-)

Answer (score 0):

A simple google search on jquery rotate color brings up this

http://buildinternet.com/2009/09/its-a-rainbow-color-changing-text-and-backgrounds/

for a blinking effect, You could always run a function every second or half second using setInterval which would toggle a class using jquery

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
function switch() {

   $("p").toggleClass("comic-sans");

}

setInterval("switch()", 1000);
```

Comment: `setInterval(switch, 1000);` would be better - strings inside timeouts/intervals are not preferrable

Answer (score 0):

Create a function that accepts a color as a variable. In the function, based on the color passed, determine which color to use next. Change the text color `element.style.color = '#FF0000';`. Still in the function, call `setTimeout()` and pass the function with the "new" color. Then, on `$(document).ready` call the color changing function.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this:

```
//Click the Fade out button
$("#fadeOut").click(function(){
    fadeItOut();
});

var fadeItOut = function() {
  $("p").fadeOut("slow", function(){
      fadeItIn();
  });
};

var fadeItIn = function() {
    $("p").fadeIn("fast", fadeItOut());
};
```